# How do I read "don't take" in a linked way with American accent?

Tags: pronunciation

> I **don’t take** too kindly to people telling me what to do.

I'm aware of the rule for double t of reading in linked way -- t t turns to d.

But here I think "don't take" turns to "don't dake" would be a little wierd --  sounds like "don't dick".

How do you think about this?

Comment: I think you may not have learned the correct rule. English doesn't have a rule about the pronunciation of "double t": the rule for weakening /t/ is based on the position of stress and the surrounding sounds, not on the spelling.

Comment: You can see some descriptions of the rule here: [Why isn't the T in “relative” flapped?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423221)